# Connecting Amazon Redshift to PowerBI - Error Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, powerbi-desktop

I am getting this message when connecting PowerBI to my Amazon Redshift account.

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState 08S01] could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "redshift-test-leo.ctwhewjldisv.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com" (3.129.150.228) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

I ticked "yes" in:

> Allow instances and devices outside the VPC connect to your database through the cluster endpoint - and even added the elastic IP.

Where can I make sure to have the port and IP accessible so I can make the connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is PowerBI running? Is it on an Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC? What is the configuration of the security group on your Redshift cluster?

Comment: Thanks, @JohnRotenstein! - I found the setting for the security group to allow external connections; now, I can pull data in PowerBi. Don't fully understand the rules, but it works! LOL